# How to "Fill Series" (Linear step value) in MySQL like in Excel?

Tags: mysql, excel, increment, series, minimum

In Excel, filling series with linear step value is simple. How do I do that in MySQL?

(1) SELECT * FROM `blog_posts` where `postid` = 5 ORDER BY `rowid` ASC

I get this query result from a huge table:

```
rowid   postid    Unix_TimeStamp
100     5          1000000000
135     5          1656885375
142     5          1885649882
208     5          1928211766
```

(2)Next, I I need to alter the values of Unix_TimeStamp. I want to leave the first row (rowid=100) alone, then every row's Unix_TimeStamp is 100 higher than the previous row's. The result would be:

```
rowid   postid    Unix_TimeStamp
100     5          1000000000
135     5          1000000100
142     5          1000000200
208     5          1000000300
```

Thanks a lot for generous replies.

Comment: Please note that in (2), I need to alter the values of Unix_TimeStamp THANK YOU!

Comment: So you want to update the unix_timestampt based on the previous one. Please check the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897366/mysql-update-column-based-on-previous-row-same-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL update column based on previous row (same column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897366/mysql-update-column-based-on-previous-row-same-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql 5.x you can do this like

In  mysql 8 you have the window function [rownumber](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE blog_posts  (
  `rowid` INTEGER,
  `postid` INTEGER,
  `Unix_TimeStamp` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO blog_posts 
  (`rowid`, `postid`, `Unix_TimeStamp`)
VALUES
  ('100', '5', '1000000000'),
  ('135', '5', '1656885375'),
  ('142', '5', '1885649882'),
  ('208', '5', '1928211766');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
`rowid`, `postid`
,(SELECT MIN(`Unix_TimeStamp`) FROM blog_posts where postid = 5 ) + @rn *100 `Unix_TimeStamp`
 ,@rn := @rn + 1 ronn
FROM blog_posts, (SELECT @rn := 0) a
where postid = 5 
ORDER BY rowid ASC;

| rowid | postid | Unix_TimeStamp | ronn |
| ----- | ------ | -------------- | ---- |
| 100   | 5      | 1000000000     | 1    |
| 135   | 5      | 1000000100     | 2    |
| 142   | 5      | 1000000200     | 3    |
| 208   | 5      | 1000000300     | 4    |



  UPDATE blog_posts bp INNER JOIN (SELECT 
`rowid`, `postid`
,(SELECT MIN(`Unix_TimeStamp`) FROM blog_posts where postid = 5 ) + @rn *100 `Unix_TimeStamp`
 ,@rn := @rn + 1 ronn
FROM blog_posts, (SELECT @rn := 0) a
where postid = 5 
ORDER BY rowid ASC) t1 ON bp.rowid = t1.rowid
```

### SET bp.Unix_TimeStamp =  t1.Unix_TimeStamp;

```
[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/4)
```

Comment: Thanks. It created the table with temp value ronn fine. But what's the command to match Unix_TimeStamp to the original query result one row by one row. In other words, I need to alter the original query result's Unix_TimeStamp

Comment: I added the update command. if you want to do that for all postid  the hole thing gets somewhat more c0omlicated.

Comment: THANK YOU so much! Being a non-coder, I can't thank you enough!!! Yes, it worked!